# Insert recordset into SQL Server Table (VB ADODB)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table on Excel, range A1:Sn (where n is the LastRow). Previously I used to  to loop in each row and insert it one by one.

This works fine, and I can resort back to it, but I am looking to insert the entire recordset `("A1:S" & LastRow)` into SQL Table, rather than looping row by row.

The reason for this is if I am inserting as a whole recordset will be treated as 1x operation, and therefore will make generating a receipt id for multiple users significantly easier.

**Code**

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
dim i as long
dim LastRow as long
LastRow = Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row

con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=LO1WPFSASDB001 ; Initial Catalog=database; User ID=username; Password=password; Trusted_Connection=no"
rs.Open "SELECT * from table;", con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

   With rs
for i = 1 to LastRow
  .addnew
  !somevalue = range("A1:S" & LastRow)
  .update
next
.Close
End With
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
```

I cannot seem to get it to work. I would appreciate your input.

Comment: Call the update after the loop?

Comment: Sorry.. Please elaborate?

Comment: You can add to the recordset, I think, and then update once you've made your updates.

Comment: Consider using MS Access to store data in tables for bulk append queries to SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you need to change the loop structure.

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConn As String
Dim i As Long, j As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim vDB

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset


LastRow = Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
vDB = Sheets("Project_Name").Range("A1:S" & LastRow)

strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=LO1WPFSASDB001 ; Initial Catalog=database; User ID=username; Password=password; Trusted_Connection=no"

    With Rs
        .ActiveConnection = strConn
        .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Open
        For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
            .AddNew
            For j = 1 To UBound(vDB, 2)
                .Fields(j) = vDB(i, j)
            Next j
            .Update
        Next i
    End With
   With Rs
End With

Set Rs = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to loop the data on excel and insert/add it.

Following your current code. The second loop is to insert the columns.

```
for i = 1 to LastRow
    .addnew
    For n = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
        .Fields(n).Value = Cells(i, n + 1)
    Next n
    .update
next
```

I would take a different approach to avoid the second loop. Instead of using .addnew I would loop the data in excel, create the INSERT Strings and do an .Execute "INSERT ..." instead. You can skip the rs.Open using this method, just opening the connection and executing on it is fine.

```
for i = 1 to LastRow
    sqlString = "INSERT INTO TableName (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4...) VALUES (Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 4)...)"
    con.Execute(sqlString)
next
```

Edit: Using the insert method, you must enclose text values with ' marks otherwise the INSERT statement will return an invalid value type.

Answer (score -1):

Following-up on Ricardo A.  In addition to wrapping text, you need to escape existing apostrophes as well.  Helps to have a function.

```
Function Wrap(Val) As String
    Wrap = "'" & VBA.Replace(CStr(Val), "'", "''") & "'"
End Function
```

There are actually three functions that I use.

```
Function WrapValue(Val) As String
    WrapValue = "'" & VBA.Replace(CStr(Val), "'", "''") & "'"
End Function

Function WrapSQLDate(d) As String
    WrapSQLDate = Format(d, "'yyyy-mm-dd'")
End Function

Function WrapSQLDateTime(d) As String
    WrapSQLDateTime = Format(d, "'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'")
End Function
```

Then call.

```
for i = 1 to LastRow
    sqlString = "INSERT INTO TableName (" & Wrap(Field1) & "," Wrap(Field2) & ...)"
    con.Execute(sqlString)
next
```

Comment: Hello SQL Injection. No amount of quoting will prevent malicious input from getting executed. In the [typical example](https://xkcd.com/327/), storing `'); DROP TABLE Students; ---` in the last column will delete an entire table. Replacing apostrophes won't work either. There are always ways to bypass such weak cleanup attempts

Comment: Another serious problem is that this code will generate *localized* strings from decimals or dates, resulting in crashes at best or bad data in the worst case.

Comment: Agreed.  I use stored procedures for apps.  I use the above whenever I'm importing records myself for things like exports from other databases when I can't query the tables directly.  I use three different functions.  I updated the answer with all three.

Comment: Stop using *any* of them. Use proper parameters instead. ADO sends parameter values *outside* the query itself as binary values to the database, so there's no chance of formatting errors or SQL injection